# Changing a value of a variable inside foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, variables, loops, foreach

I have a problem. I should change the value of a variable inside a foreach loop in php, but the value holds predefined value all the time. Here is the code:

```
$returnValue = "";
foreach($vinArray as $vinValue){
    $sql_vin_check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE vin LIKE '%:vin%'";
    $stmtvincheck  = $pdo->prepare($sql_vin_check);
    $stmtvincheck->bindParam(':vin', $vinValue);
    $stmtvincheck->execute();
    $vinCheck = $stmtvincheck->rowCount();
    $stmtvincheck->closeCursor();
    echo $vinValue;
    if($vinCheck != 0){
        $returnValue = $vinValue; break;
    }
}
return $returnValue;
```

And `$returnValue` holds the `""` value. I tried echoing `$vinValue` variable and it's not empty when the loop breaks.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `$vinCheck != 0` cause you only set `$returnValue` if it isn't equal to 0. Try changing your echo to `echo "vinValue: $vinValue vinCheck: $vinCheck";`

Comment: You should take the prepared statement (and param binding) out of the loop. That's what a prepared statement is intended for.

Comment: And against what database is this? Because the manual states "some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications."

Comment: And always do a `> 0` check and not `!= 0`. Sometimes the result is `-1` for an error !

Comment: I think you need to add the wildcards to the variable you are binding instead of the around the place holder within the prepared statement. so LIKE :vin and bindParam(':vin', '%'.$vinValue.'%').

Comment: Fred, you just solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead :

```
$returnValue = "";
foreach($vinArray as $k=>$vinValue){
    $sql_vin_check = "SELECT count(*) c FROM users WHERE vin LIKE '%:vin%'";
    $stmtvincheck  = $pdo->prepare($sql_vin_check);
    $stmtvincheck->bindParam(':vin', $vinValue);
    $stmtvincheck->execute();
    $vinCheck = $stmtvincheck->fetch();
    $stmtvincheck->closeCursor();
    if($vinCheck['c'] > 0){
        $returnValue = $vinValue; 
        break;
    }
}
return $returnValue;
```

i'd also suggest you replace the returnvalue/break with a direct return from there if nothing else is expected (this suggestion have nothing to do with your problem)